# React transition group (v1) not activating transitions on rerender

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-transition-group

I have a short quiz app and am trying to apply some animations to it. My idea is that only one question will be displayed at a time, with transitions between each one. I used `create-react-app` as boilerplate, and I'm using `react-transitions-group` v1 to apply said transitions. Right now my root component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Panel from './components/Panel';
import Results from './components/Results';
import Intro from './components/Intro';
import Form from './components/Form';

class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      collaborator: 0,
      pilot: 0,
      producer: 0,
      harmonizer: 0,
      counter: 0,
      questions: [
       'Where do you put the most effort on a day-to-day basis?',
       'What are your biggest blind spots?',
       'In what settings do you thrive?',
       'In what settings do you struggle?'
      ],
      answers: [
        [
          {answer: 'Team building', archetype: 'collaborator'},
          {answer: 'Directing strategy', archetype: 'pilot'},
          {answer: 'Driving task completion', archetype: 'producer'},
          {answer: 'Keeping processes and relationships running smoothly', archetype: 'harmonizer'}
        ],
        [
          {answer: 'Setting a clear direction and creating a personal brand', archetype: 'collaborator'},
          {answer: 'Making space for others and planning for the longterm', archetype: 'pilot'},
          {answer: 'Connecting with team members and innovating', archetype: 'producer'},
          {answer: 'Accepting ambiguity and addressing conflict', archetype: 'harmonizer'}
        ],
        [
          {answer: 'Settings where team members are seeking coaching and development', archetype: 'collaborator'},
          {answer: 'Ambiguous and high growth environments', archetype: 'pilot'},
          {answer: 'Organizations with clear structures and processes', archetype: 'producer'},
          {answer: 'Volatile settings that need to be tamed', archetype: 'harmonizer'}
        ],
        [
          {answer: 'Settings where unilateral decision making is required', archetype: 'collaborator'},
          {answer: 'Conservative environments that discourage innovation', archetype: 'pilot'},
          {answer: 'Teams where each member desires independence', archetype: 'producer'},
          {answer: 'Anywhere tough feedback needs to be given', archetype: 'harmonizer'}
        ]
      ]
    }
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    this.onSelectIntro = this.onSelectIntro.bind(this);
  }

  onSelect(value) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        [value]: prevState[value] + 1,
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      }
    })
  }

  onSelectIntro() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { counter: prevState.counter + 1 };
    })
  }

  render() {
    switch (this.state.counter) {
      case 0:
        return <Intro onClick={this.onSelectIntro}/>;
        break;
      case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
         return <Panel 
          question={this.state.questions[this.state.counter - 1]}
          answers={this.state.answers[this.state.counter - 1]}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />;
        break;
      case 5:
        return <Results />;
        break;
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

My `Panel` component is Looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function PanelOne (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Form question={props.question} answers={props.answers} onSelect={props.onSelect}/>
        </div>
    )
}

PanelOne.propTypes = {
  answers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default PanelOne;
```

`Form` is where my transitions are applied, and it looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { RadioGroup, RadioButton } from 'react-radio-buttons';
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

function Form (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <CSSTransitionGroup 
                transitionName='slide'
                transitionEnterTimeout={300}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
            >
                <h3>{props.question}</h3>
                <RadioGroup onChange={props.onSelect}>
                    {
                        props.answers.map(answer => 
                            <RadioButton key={answer.answer} value={answer.archetype}>
                                {answer.answer}
                            </RadioButton>
                        )
                    }
                </RadioGroup>
            </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    )
}

Form.propTypes = {
  answers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Form;
```

Lastly, here's my `index.css` file:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.slide-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.slide-enter.slide-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
.slide-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slide-leave.slide-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

I expect that when I click on an answer to a question, the next question will be displayed after the transition is applied. However, when I click an answer what actually happens is that the next question is displayed immediately, with no transition between the two questions. I really am at a loss for what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Your Form and Panel components are functional components, so they do not have instance.

[React Components, Elements, and Instances](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html)

> Only components declared as classes have instances, and you never create them directly: React does that for you.

So when their props change, the underlying DOM tree might be remove. This way leave animations doesn't happen.

[Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)

> When a component updates, the instance stays the same, so that state is maintained across renders.

You should try with Class components.

Comment: yup, sorry, first time i use this website... Can i still change this?

Comment: I know @K.Davis is correct, but I want to say that I really appreciate this answer nonetheless. My original question has been edited to include my `Panel` component.

Comment: @Progragamer I've changed my `Panel` and `Form` components to be class components instead of functional components (thank you for those blog posts!). I've changed nothing else in my code. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same result as before - the animation is not taking place.

Comment: Can you log componentWillUnmount and componentDidMount in Form component?

Comment: @Progragamer yeah I just added those. Each time the state changes/the thing rerenders, `componentDidMount` logs properly. However, `componentWillUnmount` doesn't log at all until `state.counter` reaches 5 and `Panel` no longer renders and is replaced by `Result`.

Comment: This is what we expect, both of them should log only once. So this is not a lifecycle issue.

Comment: @Progragamer any other ideas for what might be going on??

Comment: why there is no import for your css in your Form file? it seems to be a problem

Comment: @Progragamer Just tried adding that import, and it didn't make a difference. I don't think I need to import it anyway since that's hooked up to my app out of the box with `create-react-app`. I tested that by changing the background color in `index.css` to black, and it worked fine.

Comment: well, i've no more idea, sorry mate.